# How to Concat Arrays in Vuex getters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to return an concat Array in vuex getters but it only udpates after a hard browser refresh

```
const state = () => ({
   array1 : [{'key1':'value1'}],
   array2 : [{'key2':'value2'}, {'key3':'value3'}]
});

const getters = {
  newArray: (state) => {
    return state.array1.concat(array2);    
  },
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 1):

reason: https://cn.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#%E5%AF%B9%E4%BA%8E%E6%95%B0%E7%BB%84

OR

Try this :

```
newArray: (state) => {
    return [...state.array1,...state.array2]  
  },
```